# Shell Programming with special characters

Tags: shell, unix

```
oldstring='<tr><th> Report </th><td bgcolor="#FF0000"><font color="#FFFFFF"> STOPPED</font></td></tr>'
newstring='<tr><th> Report </th><td bgcolor="#FF0000"><font color="#FFFFFF"> STOPPED-ON-REQUIREMENT</font></td></tr>'
#the above strings are from HTML File

TIME=$(date '+%H%M%S')

if [ $TIME -ge 110000 ] -a [ $TIME -le 160000 ]

then

grep -rl STOPPED /temp/report.html | xargs sed -i "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g"

if grep -q STOPPED "/temp/report.html"; then
( echo "Subject: Servers || Alert Server Stopped - Servers  HEALTH REPORT";echo "To: rajesh@xyz.com";echo "From:abc@xyz.com"; echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; echo "Content-Type: text/html"; echo "Content-Disposition: inline";echo "Importance: High"; cat //tmp/health.html ; ) | sendmail -t
else
( echo "Subject: Servers || Servers  HEALTH REPORT";echo "To: rajesh@xya.com";echo "From:abc@xyz.com"; echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; echo "Content-Type: text/html"; echo "Content-Disposition: inline"; cat //tmp/health.html ; ) | sendmail -t
fi

elif grep -q STOPPED "//tmp/health.html"; then
( echo "Subject: Servers || Alert Server Stopped - Servers  HEALTH REPORT";echo "To: rajesh@xya.com";echo "From:abc@xyz.com"; echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; echo "Content-Type: text/html"; echo "Content-Disposition: inline";echo "Importance: High"; cat //tmp/health.html ; ) | sendmail -t
else
( echo "Subject: Servers || Servers  HEALTH REPORT";echo "To: rajesh@xya.com";echo "From:abc@xyz.com"; echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; echo "Content-Type:text/html"; echo "Content-Disposition: inline"; cat //tmp/health.html ; ) | sendmail -t
fi
```

i am trying to grep an HTML file and if finds STOPPED word i am replacing it with other requirement words based on time. and send the report to my team.

but when i try to run i get different errors as below

```
./tempsendmail.sh[8]: syntax error at line 14 : `<' unexpected

./tempsendmail.sh[18]: syntax error at line 30 : `)' unexpected
```

Comment: This is too much irrelevant code. For the first error, you should be able to boil this down to 1 line of variable declaration and 1 line of `sed`. Fixing that will probably fix the 2nd error. Please clean up your Q with the smallest test case of input, required output, current output and current code. Good luck.

Comment: You'd have to escape the special characters. You're better off generating the report more sanely or potentially not doing it in shell.

Comment: @shellter , will try to cut-short the variable deceleration.

Comment: There is plenty I would change, but as for sed errors, when using s/// you can change the / to something else.  In your case, because your text contains / it will not work.  Try changing to | or %, ie s|str1|str2|

Comment: Is there any other way i can use it? if not grep and sed?. i have to take entire line of html file with special characters because in an HTML file i have somany words that matches "STOPPED".
My requirement was to match "Report" and "STOPPED" words in same line and to replace STOPPED word in that line only.

Answer (score -1):

i got the answer and i made it happen this way(works on Linux):

newstring=grep -E STOPPED- /tmp/temp1.txt <-- since i can't assign entire line with special characters i had to put that line in a temp file and grep,assign it as an variable
oldstring=grep -v REQUIREMENT /tmp/tempS1.txt <-- same as above

TIME=$(date '+%H%M%S')

if [ "$TIME" -gt 104000 -a "$TIME" -lt 191000 ]
then
sed -i "/Report123/ c\|$newstring|" /tmp/temp1.txt   <-- this will find "Report123" and replace entire line with newstring